# Referencing of projects in .Net solution issue

Tags: c#, .net, dll, architecture, solution

I am working on building an architecture of a new application. My doubt is as below

I have say 3 projects in my solution A, B, C

> Project C is referenced in Project A
>
> Project C is referenced in Project B
>
> Project B is referenced in Project A

Is such kind of architecture OK? Can it cause any issue in future?

Answer (score 2):

As long you don't have circular dependencies, it's fine.
It's hard to say whether your architecture makes sense because you have provided no detailed information about the VS projects.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that's fine. C seems to some kind of shared library used by A and B.
Additinally A is dependent from B. I don't see any difficutlies as long as you don't get circular references, which will not work.